# How to send data from Android device to My PC

Tags: android

I'm a beginner to android. I need to send my data from a android App to my PC over the internet.As I know there are some ways to do it:
1-Socket Programming
2-Web Service
3-Cloud Connection
I tried first one and Socket Programming works when server and client are on same machine. But otherwise not.  For Web service I need a "URL" (valid).I don't have enough knowledge in Cloud connection. I don't know how I can do it. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Socket works between different machines too. You need a server configured on your PC and a client configured on your phone. What kind of data you will send?

Comment: @spezzino : Thanks. 
I need to send text, maybe just a few words. I did Socket same way(server on my PC and client in my phone). But server didn't get any thing

Comment: Implement a server using [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), there are multiple [packages](https://npmjs.org) that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know if you actually have a server?

If yes, you should write a small server application which will receive data from your mobile device and process it. The server app could provide the ressource for download from your pc.

if you don't have a server, i don't know how you could do it directly via the internet, i have not yet done anyting like this. both devices had to be online, otherwise, a server would be of need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the following I would recommend a Backend-as-a-Service solution:

Do you need to store the data? Use [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) or [GoInstant](https://goinstant.com).
Do you just want to send some data, and then forget them? Maybe [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com) could be of use. All of them provide Android SDKs.

And what do you mean with "my PC"? A browser-based interface / a stand-alone application in Java...?